# How display pointcloud messages in browser using rosjs?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, 
I have found the same [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/41223/how-to-publish-kinect-laser-scan-2d-image-in-a-browser/) but the answer seems to be obsolete.
Concerning, [this link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjs_tutorials/Tutorials/Visualization). I can't find some JavaScript files used in this tutorial. Especially *visualization.js*.

They are not included in rosbridge nor wviz packages. I can't find them on [rosbridge website](http://rosbridge.org/doku.php?id=start)  
Are they obsolete ? Where can i find the last version?

By the way, how can I display my pointcloud from ROS messages in my webpage using rosjs.
Thanks,
BeuBeu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43781/how-display-pointcloud-messages-in-browser-using-rosjs-?/) by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Beubeu,

as Dejan pointed out wviz now lives in [bosch_web_visualization](http://wiki.ros.org/bosch_web_visualization) stack. Wviz uses javascript files included in

- rosjs_visualization (this package might be what you're looking for btw),
- rosjs_common, and,
- rosjs_resources

Just to test, you could trying installing wviz and adding a laser scan display in the scene.

If (that works) && (you want to make your own custom web page) && (you need help) then let's take the topic to [bosch_web_visualization user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/bosch_web_visualization-users).

If you are interested in visualizing point clouds, then please use Brown's pcl_filter package (it will throttle the data and prevent Chrome from crashing). In the near future rosjs_visualization (and wviz) will use compression to reduce the bandwidth consumption. Until that day, pcl_filter is our best friend.

Ben

---

Originally posted by [bener suay](https://answers.ros.org/users/1003/bener-suay/) with karma: 178 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2